# Is it possible to declare constexpr class in a header and define it in a separate .cpp file?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I have a class `Dimension` which I defined (like all my classes) in a file Dimension.h:

```
class Dimension
{
public:

    constexpr Dimension() noexcept;

    constexpr Dimension(int w, int h) noexcept;

    int width;
    int height;

};
```

I thought I could, like in all my classes, put the definition in a separate Dimension.cpp:

```
#include "Dimension.h"

constexpr Dimension::Dimension() noexcept : width(0), height(0) {}

constexpr Dimension::Dimension(int w, int h) noexcept : width(w), height(h) {}
```

But when I try to use the class, the compiler tells me:

warning: inline function '`constexpr Dimension::Dimension()`' used but never defined

and while linking:

undefined reference to '`pong::graphics::Dimension::Dimension()`'

(same with the other constructor)

If I define the class in the header like so:

```
class Dimension
{
public:

    constexpr Dimension() noexcept : width(0), height(0) {}

    constexpr Dimension(int w, int h) noexcept : width(w), height(h) {}

    int width;
    int height;

};
```

and omit the .cpp file, everything works fine.

I'm using GCC 4.9.2. Why does separate definition not work?

Comment: The whole point of a `constexpr` function is to allow evaluating the function at compile time. Which would be rather difficult to pull off if the compiler cannot see the body of said function.

Comment: I already suspected that, but I'm not quite sure if I can explain (with references maybe) why it happens exactly. I did not find anything about this while googling, so I figured a new question for this was appropriate.

Comment: _@TimoTürschmann_ _"but I'm not quite sure if I can explain (with references maybe) why it happens ..."_ To reword @IgorTandetnik 's comment a bit: The compiler needs to see a `constexpr` hcompletely expanded whenever it's used, to insert the correct expression in place. Linking stage is too late.

Comment: If you insist on chapter and verse: **7.1.5/2** `constexpr` functions and `constexpr` constructors are implicitly inline. **3.2/4** An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

If a `constexpr` function is not defined inside the header, the compiler can not see the definition of the `constexpr` functions while compiling all the other source files.

Obviously, if it can't see the definition of the functions, it can't perform the steps necessary to calculate them at compile-time. Thus all `constexpr` functions must be defined everywhere they are used.

Thanks @IgorTandetnik:
**[dcl.constexpr] §7.1.5/2**

> `constexpr` functions and `constexpr` constructors are implicitly inline.

**[basic.def.odr] §3.2/4**

> An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used.

Answer (score 24):

What you're asking can be accomplished, with a significant limitation: the *constexpr* function can then only be called from inside the translation unit (i.e. source file) where it is defined. This is not appropriate for the example you gave, since the constructor is meant to be part of the class' public interface. However it can be very useful in other cases, e.g. to define private methods as *constexpr* and then use their return values in expressions that need to be known at compile time, e.g. template instantiations, switch statement labels, etc.

Comment: It was very confusing reading the first answer and then looking at compiling source code where there are constexpr functions defined in both .h and .cpp files. The accepted solution above is actually incorrect by omitting this essential detail.

Comment: @okovko The accepted solution says "all constexpr functions must be defined everywhere they are used." That's your "essential detail".